# SCNScene how to change eulerAngles?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit, scnnode

How can I change eulerAngles on SCNScene?

```
scene.pointOfView?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x:0, y:20, z:0)
```

doesn't work.
What I need to change euler? I need to use 3D arrow in compass app.

Comment: did you try SCNVector3Make instead of SCNVector3

Comment: Yes, doesn't work